# C++ Как в CMakeLists.txt указать компилятору путь к заголовочным файлам?

Tags: c++, компиляция, cmake, include, cmakelists

У меня такая проблема, при подключении заголовочных файлов в проекте постоянно приходится писать что-то типа того:

```
#include "../../include/Backend/show_result.h"
```

Как в CMakeLists.txt указать относительные пути компилятору, чтобы получилось вот так:

```
#include "Backend/show_result.h"
```

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html А когда включаете такие заголовки, то следует использовать `#include <Backend/show_result.h>`

Answer (score 0):

У компилятора есть параметр -I вот как пример.

`gcc -c -I/home/me/development/skia sample.c`

Что по факту делает все файлы как include root.

`...nt/skia/super.hpp`

Может быть декларировано как `#include <super.hpp>`

Извини я старпёр, ещё до сих пор пользуюсь старым cmake - `make all`